# How to set case of BEM in VSCode?

Tags: bem

I've just started learning BEM methodology and typed the following code in VS Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="search-form search-form_disabled"></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, I've installed BEM Helper - the VSCode's extension that checks your code according to conventions of BEM.
It threw me this warning:
**BEM - Class names must be in kebab case**

I tried to change the settings of extension, to be precise, *bemHelper.classNameCase*, using command palette. But when I typed this command, it output me dropdown menu with one variant could be chosen from. And there was no *any* variant!
Is there any other way to set case?

Comment: I think the `_` in `search-form_disabled` is the one thing that violates kebab case here. Or are you searching for something different? It should be `search-form-disabled` for full kebab case.

Comment: disabled is modifier, so it must be written in snake case, according to bem conventions. The problem is that bem helper doesn't recognize the modifier. It thinks it's a part of class. So I decided to change the class name's case, as I described in my problem

Comment: You may try using an alternative naming convention (https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#alternative-naming-schemes). Personally I like "2 dashes style" more, where a modifier is appended with `--` instead of `_`. To me it looks neater and cleaner. Not sure it'll solve your problem because most probably you'll still have to use underscores for elements (for example, `block__element`). But who knows, maybe your helper will be okay with this option.